# How to expand a dynamic object wthout disrupting its existing members?

Tags: c#, asp.net, expandoobject, dynamicobject

I have a dynamic object called Manifest and have members added in it like

```
 public dynamic  manifest={
      Type=30, 
      components ={ .. something}
          }
```

I  want to expand this dynamic object to accomodate more members.
What's the syntax for this..?

The data that i want to add looks like this:

```
verificationData:
{
  hash: "aadfj4j43w2sfsj43s", //security hash of the bytes in machineState, in4mConfig, components, tasks
  signature: "jf0f9s9f302kfs9sffs" //signature of the hash
},
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: You have the answer in your tags: [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My question is whether ExpandoObject overwrites existing members

Comment: You should at least add the type of `manifest`

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did without ExpandoObject

```
 dynamic signingInfo = new JObject();
 signingInfo.verificationData = new JObject();
 signingInfo.verificationData.signature = installation.Signature;
 signingInfo.verificationData.hashedValue = installation.Hash;

installation.Manifest.verificationData = signingInfo;
```